# Symfony2 HTML5 integer input and validator

Tags: html, validation, symfony, integer

I'm using symfony2 and I have an input field, I need people to put numbers in it, but I'm having trouble with validation.

I'm validating the field with this code:

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('Identification', new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Write something in identification field, cannot be blank.')));
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('Identification', new Type(array('message' => 'You must write a number', 'type' => 'integer'))); 
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('Identification', new MinLength(array('message' => '5 digits, minimun', 'limit' => 5)));
```

First of all, how can I delete the arrows that appear next to the field? (HTML5 functionality). I don't like them at all, and the numbers that users have to put in the input field are > 500000, so I'm pretty sure they won't use this annoying -in this case- arrows.

I have tried, in MyEntity**Type**.php file, adding the word 'text' to make the field appear without the arrows

```
->add('identification','text')
```

I works that way, but if I do it, then the validation error 'you must write a number' it always appearing, no matter if I'm writing a number (which it shouldn't show any errors).

What I want is an input field where the user can write a number, and I want to validate it.

Should I use just a REGEX validation to indicate that I want just numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to validate integers in Symfony2 form is to add a minimum constraint. That way input are converted to integers and validated.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Min(limit = 0)
 */
private $myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('Identification', new Type(array('message' => 'You must write a number', 'type' => 'digit')));
```